# How do I count values in cells with multiple values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a data frame that is filled with data that was pulled from an API. There are a couple of columns that have with multiple values, the values in the cells are names. Do I have to split those cells in order to count each name or is there a way to count the values in each cell by doing the str.split with the value_count? Here is an example:

employees on trip

`jeff, jerome, betsy,`

`jerome,`

`betsy, jerome`

`jeff,`

output:Absolutely,

`output:`
`Employee name    Count`
`Jeff             2`
`jerome           3`
`betsy            2`

I don't know if this is translating well but in the column there are multiple names in the cells. Can I count those without splitting?

Comment: why don't you provide a clear, reproducible, minimal example DataFrame and the matching expected output?

Comment: Absolutely,

Column

employees on trip

jeff, jerome, betsy,

jerome,

betsy, jerome

jeff,

output:
Employee name    Count
Jeff                         2
jerome                   3
betsy                     2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you check if the answer gave your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str split in each cell

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['employees']=["jeff, jerome, betsy","jeff, jerome","jeff"]
df['count']=[len(df.employees.iloc[i].split(",")) for i in range(len(df))]
```

[image: results]

Comment: yes one moment.